# How do I correctly mark the active navigation link when that link represents two URLs?

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular5, navigationbar

In my Angular 5.2 app, profiles have two pages: *Details* and *Activity*. The default page for any profile is *Details*, so the routes are set up like this **(full Typescript sample of the router config at the end of the post)**:

```js
{ path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'details', component: ProfileDetailsComponent },
    { path: 'activity', component: ProfileActivityComponent },
    { path: '**', component: ProfileDetailsComponent }
  ]
}
```

`ProfileComponent` handles the root of both profile pages. It has a page header and a navigation bar, and includes a `<router-outlet>` element for the Profile Details/Activity Components (loaded depending on the route above). Its HTML looks like this:

```html
<div> <!-- some header stuff --> </div>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="./details">Details</a></li>
    <li><a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="./activity">Activity</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="page-content">
  <!-- ProfileDetailsComponent or ProfileActivityComponent will be loaded here -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm using the RouterLinkActive directive to give these tabs in the middle the `active` class when I'm on the right page. However, this runs into an issue:

- The Details tab (the first item) correctly gets the `active` class when I'm on `/users/profile/3/details`.
- It does not, however, get the `active` class when I'm on `/users/profile/3`, even though that's functionally the same page — we still need to show you're on the Details page.

If I instead write that link as the following...

```html
<a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="./">Details</a>
```

Then this gets the `active` class *anywhere* on the current route, even when I'm inside the Activity tab.

**How can I get this link, which represents one (functional) page reachable via two URLs, to get the 'active' class on either URL?** Is there a method I should be using other than routerLinkActive in this circumstance?

Currently to skirt this issue I have set up `/users/profile/:id` to redirect to `/users/profile/:id/details`, but I'd prefer to not have that redirect.

---

## The router config for my app

### app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'users', loadChildren: 'app/users/users.module#UsersModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

#### users-routing.module.ts

(All the below-defined routes are relative to `/users/` per the above route from app-routing.)

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: UserListComponent },
  { path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'details', component: ProfileDetailsComponent },
      { path: 'activity', component: ProfileActivityComponent },
      { path: '**', component: ProfileDetailsComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UsersRoutingModule { }
```

The current patch fix (mentioned at the end of the problem section above) has that `**` route instead set up with:

```js
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'details' }
```

...but as mentioned I'd really prefer to keep the `/profiles/:id` route available without direction.

Comment: Easiest solution is to track the route in your component by subscribing to `Router` events: https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events, and setting a bool based on the path (using plain ol' js/regex). You can then set `active` class with `[ngStyle]="{'active':customIsActive}"`

Comment: @Z.Bagley That looks like a reasonable answer to me. Would you be interested in posting it as one? (Also note a shortcut for that syntax is available: `[class.active]="customIsActive"`)

Comment: I posted the answer... and I learned something new which is always a plus. Wasn't even aware of that neat shorthand, so ty for that

Answer (score 5):

Is hard to help without actually live testing the app, but try the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: UserListComponent },
  { path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: ProfileDetailsComponent }
      { path: 'details', component: ProfileDetailsComponent },
      { path: 'activity', component: ProfileActivityComponent },
    ]
  }
];
```

Also, add `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:false}"` to skip strict validation on the route:

```
<li><a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/details" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:false}>Details</a></li>
```

**Edit1:**

Based on your comment I'm confused, if `/profile/:id` should go to Details, then the Routes should not be like this instead?

```
const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: UserListComponent },
      { path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileDetailsComponent , // not ProfileComponent  but: ProfileDetailsComponent 
        children: [
          { path: 'details', component: ProfileDetailsComponent },
          { path: 'activity', component: ProfileActivityComponent },
        ]
      }
    ];
```

Sorry if I misunderstood, is my last working hour and my brain is fried... xD

Comment: This one didn't appear to work, but I appreciate the assistance. I had to set routerLink to `./details` or `details` since `/details` pointed me back to the root of the application (`localhost:4200/details`). However `details` or `./details` combined with the implementation of a blank path route and the `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:false}"` attribute set, didn't result in the Details link getting the Active class on the default profile path (`/profile/:id`).

Comment: I've updated my question post to clarify what's going on given you mentioned being confused -- ProfileComponent contains some of its own content, including the navigation bar in question, and includes ProfileDetails/Activity as a nested child included via a router-outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to track the route in your component by subscribing to `Router` events: [Angular - Router: Router Events](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events), and setting a bool based on the path (using plain ol' js/regex).

You can then set `active` class with `[ngStyle]="{'active':customIsActive}"`, or shorthand `[class.active]="customIsActive"`